# Loading local JavaScript files In Vue 3 With metaInfo() scripts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using a third-party HTML template.  The template's CSS files are loaded via import statements in the `<style>` tags within App.vue without issue.  However, the template also requires two JavaScript files to be loaded.  In the template itself, this is done via `<script>` tags at the bottom of the `<body>` (*as is commonly done*).  However, Vue doesn't like that, so I'm attempting to load the scripts via the `metaInfo()` method within App.vue's `<script>`.  An example of how I'm doing this is below:

```
<script>
    import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.vue"

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        metaInfo: {
            title: 'My Awesome App',
            titleTemplate: 'My Awesome App | %s',
            script: [
                {
                    once: true,
                    type: 'text/javascript',
                    src: './assets/js/bundle.js?ver=3.0.3',
                    body: true,
                    defer: true,
                    callback: () => (console.log('bundle.js loaded'))
                },
                {
                    once: true,
                    type: 'text/javascript',
                    src: './assets/js/scripts.js?ver=3.0.3',
                    body: true,
                    defer: true,
                    callback: () => (console.log('scripts.js loaded'))
                }
            ],
        },
        components: {
            MyComponent
        }
    }
</script>
```

The scripts don't appear to be loading into the browser's memory.  To test, I added that `callback()` method to log a message to the console when the scripts loaded.  However, no messages are being logged.

**EDIT:** It should be noted, the two scripts do not export anything, so importing them with statements such as seen below causes errors:

`import * as BundleScript from './assets/js/bundle.js'`

Comment: Vue doesn't have "metaInfo". If your case relies on specific libraries, the question needs to address them, not Vue in general.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm guessing you are referring to vue-meta???  I use `metaInfo()` without issue for other features (such as `bodyAtturs: {}`), and I haven't installed vue-meta, (primarily because I'm using Vue 3 and vue-meta doesn't currently support it).  There must be at least some support for it (maybe undocumented?)